# Wordpress Twitter Plugin where I can render HTML from raw data

Tags: php, twitter, wordpress, wordpress-theming

New to WordPress (and PHP) and am converting a bootstrap template from WrapBootstrap into a WordPress theme. The template has a section for 'recent tweets' which I would like to keep the look and feel of.

From what I can see, all of the twitter plugins render out their own HTML that can't be modified. Is there anyway I can get the raw tweet data and loop through it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a twitter feeds plugin for wordpress and you can use it. If you have any problem using it, I can help you to get what you need.

Here is the link to the plugin I developed.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-twitter-feeds/